# pandas dataframe to_csv works with sep='\n' but not sep='\t'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I try to print my large dataframe to csv file but the tab separation `sep='\t'` does not work. I then test with newline `sep='\n'`, it seems work ok, break all the elements by newline. What are possibly wrong here?

The code is so simple like

```
df_M.to_csv('report'+filename, header=True, sep='\t', index=False)
```

The example of data (the protein column is very long), I mark where to separate by `|`

```
"protein |  cl      | pept |    [M] |  [M+1H+]1+ |  [M+2H+]2+"      
"ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - Homo sapiens (Human)|    0|   AWAVAR|        672.37072|            673.378| out-of-range"        
"ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - Homo sapiens (Human)|    0|  TPVSDR| 673.3394900000002|  674.3467700000002|  out-of-range"       
"ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - Homo sapiens (Human)|    0|  NYAEAK| 694.3285900000001|  695.3358700000001|  out-of-range"       
"
```

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I think you have problem with `read_csv`. If filter only first 10 rows it failed too? By `df_M.iloc[:10].to_csv('report'+filename, header=True, sep='\t', index=False)`

Comment: You mean if I replace my `.to_csv` using your example? It works. I can get the first ten rows in the csv file but compact together (not tab-separated) @jezrael

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? It seems there is problem all data are in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saving the data as .tsv format? 
your data is tsv file as you are separating the data with '\t' which is tab.
csv file must be separated by ",".

If you wanna save data with .csv format you need to separate by ","

Link for .csv RFC. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 1):

There is problem all rows are in `"` and then get one column `DataFrame`.

So need `quoting=3` for `QUOTE_NONE` and then remove trailing `"` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df_M= pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', quoting=3, skipinitialspace=True)
df_M.iloc[:, 0] = df_M.iloc[:, 0].str.strip('"')
df_M.iloc[:, -1] = df_M.iloc[:, -1].str.strip('"')
df_M.columns = df_M.columns.str.strip('"')
print (df_M)

                                            protein   cl         pept   \
0  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...         0  AWAVAR   
1  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...         0  TPVSDR   
2  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...         0  NYAEAK   

        [M]   [M+1H+]1+      [M+2H+]2+  
0  672.37072   673.37800  out-of-range  
1  673.33949   674.34677  out-of-range  
2  694.32859   695.33587  out-of-range
```

Another solution is read data to one column and then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='^')
cols = df.columns.str.split('|').tolist() 
df_M = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split('|', expand=True)
df_M.columns = cols
print (df_M)

                                            protein    cl            pept   \
0  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...          0     AWAVAR   
1  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...          0     TPVSDR   
2  ALBU_HUMAN_UPS Serum albumin (Chain 26-609) - ...          0     NYAEAK   

                 [M]            [M+1H+]1+        [M+2H+]2+  
0           672.37072              673.378    out-of-range  
1   673.3394900000002    674.3467700000002    out-of-range  
2   694.3285900000001    695.3358700000001    out-of-range
```

And last [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) working nice:

```
df_M.to_csv('report'+filename, header=True, sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
df_M.to_csv('report'+filename, header=True, sep='\t', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

You can also see here [Pandas Data Frame to_csv with more separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983286/pandas-data-frame-to-csv-with-more-separator)

Or it is likely to be a version problem since I couldn't reproduce the problem, see `pd.__version__` provided that the last one is '0.21.0'

Hope this is useful